# cassandra : name provided was not in the list of valid column labels error

Tags: cassandra

i'm using cassandra 1.2.8. i have a column family like below:

```
CREATE TABLE word_probability (
   word text,
   category text,
   probability double,
   PRIMARY KEY (word,category)
);
```

when i use query like this:

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM word_probability WHERE word='%s' AND category='%s';";
```

it works well but for some words i get this message:

```
     name provided was not in the list of valid column labels error
```

every thing is ok and i don't know why i get this error :(

Comment: Do you know for which words you got this error?

Comment: words like: sebelius , iaea's, arming, indexes, tranquility and so on...

Comment: That error comes from Cassandra JDBC driver. Can you check if specifying all the columns (i.e ``SELECT word, category, probability FROM word_probability ...`` works for you?

Comment: no! i try this query but i get same error

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong except mixing up cql with sql. Cql doesn't support `%` wildcards.

Comment: you mean i use what instead "word='%s'"?